# JConsole losing connection when using GuavaCacheMetrics

Tags: java, spring, guava, jmx, jconsole

JConsole keeps getting disconnected from the MBeans server when I use GuavaCacheMetrics.monitor(...). It connects, then immediately alerts "Connection Lost: Reconnect?". The Spring application outputs: "The server has decided to close this client connection" when JConsole disconnects.

I'm using Spring Boot 2.4.0

Comment: Have it too… any clues?

Comment: Removing this dependency fixed it: micrometer-registry-jmx

Comment: Well that was actually needed, so it didn't fix it...